# Clip vector on Geoprocesing QGIS 2.18.13, global name 'features' is not defined

Tags: qgis, polygon, clip, update

I want to clip a vector polygon with a boundary vector polygon but the process is failing. I am getting the error, "global name 'features' is not defined See log for more details". I don't know what is causing this error.

[image]

Comment: I got the same problem. Solved by using 2.14

Comment: Is there any way to solve it without using another version?

Comment: you can modify the code in your QGIS instalation for  solve it

Comment: @FranciscoRaga any pointers on where and how to modify the code?

Answer (score 9):

This is a bug in [2.18.13](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17248). fixed in new release.