# Clip vector on Geoprocesing QGIS 2.18.13 "Algorithm Clip starting... global name 'features' is not defined"

Tags: qgis, polygon, clip, qgis-2.18

I'm using QGIS version 2.18.13 and I'm getting the error message while clipping a layer line within a polygon.

Error message:

> "Algorithm Clip starting... global name 'features' is not defined"

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Hajasminum! I believe a practically similar question was asked recently: [Clip vector on Geoprocesing QGIS 2.18.13, global name 'features' is not defined](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257333/clip-vector-on-geoprocesing-qgis-2-18-13-global-name-features-is-not-defined)

Comment: Should I downlaod QGIS 2.14?

Comment: I would suggest downloading QGIS 2.18.14 which should contain the fix for this error :). Just download from their main site: [http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html)